# Filtering a List with an array items

Tags: c#, linq

i need to filter a list with strings in an array. Below code doesn't return the expected result.

```
List<searchModel> obj=//datasource is assigned from database

mystring="city1,city2";
string[] subs = mystring.Split(',');
foreach (string item in subs)
{
    obj = obj.Where(o => o.property.city.ToLower().Contains(item)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is there a property in your `searchModel` class called `property`? Please post the code for the `searchModel` class.

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: What is the expected result, what is the current result?

Comment: Its a good question, you have to give some example for your output. So people will understand it easily rather than spending time to understand the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as you're using `Contains`, I'd say you could be trying to get

1. entries, `city` of which matches any city from `mystring`
2. entries, `city` of which match all cities from `mystring`

So, having (I simplified `searchModel` class, having omitted `property`):

```
List<searchModel> obj = new List<searchModel>
{
    new searchModel{city = "city1"},
    new searchModel{city = "city2"},
    new searchModel{city = "city3"}
};

var mystring = "city1,city2";
var subs = mystring.Split(',').ToList(); //let it be also List<T>
```

We can do:

```
//the 1st option
var orFilter = obj.Where(o => subs.Any(s => o.city.ToLower().Contains(s)))
                  .ToList();
//the 2nd option
var andFilter = obj.Where(o => subs.TrueForAll(s => o.city.ToLower().Contains(s)))
                   .ToList();
```

Then do a simple check

```
foreach (var o in andFilter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.city);
}
```

I'd say that the OP is equal to option 2, not option 1.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this, or something close - I haven't tested it:

```
List<searchModel> obj=//datasource is assigned from database

mystring="city1,city2";

string[] subs = mystring.Split(',');

obj = obj.Where(o => subs.Contains(o.property.city.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Comment: Arrays in C# does not have a 'Contains' method...

IndexOf can be used as well.. If Index is not -1 then it is contained in the List.

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently doing is filtering the list by ALL cities. So you'll only return results where `o.property.city` equals "city1" *and* "city2" (and any other cities you might have in the list). So you won't get any results.

To match any city in the list instead, try this:

```
var myFilteredObj = obj.Where(o => subs.Contains(o.property.city.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this codes of lines, probably will help someone and maybe someone will optimize it:

```
var jaggedArray = new string[100][];
var i = 0;
jaggedArray[i] = {"first folder","first file","first 5 files","last 5 folder"};
filter = "irs le";
var arrFilters = filter.Split(' ');
foreach (var arrFilter in arrFilters)
{
    jaggedArray[i] = jaggedArray[i].Where(p =>p.ToLower().Contains(arrFilter.ToLower())).ToArray();
    jaggedArray[i + 1] = jaggedArray[i];
    i++;
}
return jaggedArray[i]; //new array after filter
//result: "first file","first 5 files"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = obj.Where(piD => subs.Contains(piD.city)).ToList();
```

The code above will filter the `obj` `List` based on the string array.